# "Keep close to me", "keep near me" or "don't go far from me" in context?

Tags: phrase-choice

Let's say I went for a walk with a child, and I want them to be close to me so that they are safe. Which of the following sentences sound the most natural?

> Keep close to me!
>
> Keep near me!
>
> Don't go far from me!

If none of them sounds natural to communicate the message, what would a native English speaker say?

Comment: The shortest, and most common version I hear: “Stay with me.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an explanation in [5 ways to get your preschooler to stop running away from you](https://www.todaysparent.com/kids/preschool/5-ways-to-get-your-preschooler-to-stop-running-away-from-you/)
how to tell your child to stay close and not run away from you:

> We’re going to go grocery shopping now, and I need you **to stay beside me**. If you don’t, you’ll have to hold my hand or sit in the grocery cart.”

So, if you want to tell your child to stay close say **Stay beside me!**.